# How to view excel sheets in rails4 without downloading/using googledoc/microsoft office docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, viewer

In my **rails-4** application, I need to show the **excel(xls,xlsx)** file contents without using external services. The external services will be available if the documents are public. Without downloading I need to open the excel attachments.
Is there any way to do this in rails. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Excel file ?  There's a lot of required detail missing from your post.

Comment: From the rails application excel attachments can be uploaded and stored in the application . But, excel files(.xlx/.xlsx) can't be viewed inside the application like jpg/pdf etc .

Answer (score -1):

While you are using **ruby on rails**, you can open the **images**, **pdf** without download. But when we talk about **xlsx,xlx,doc** etc format file we need to download these first then we can open these in related application.
But if there is any of client requirement to open your data in same as those application. you need to develop a template where you can edit the data like as **excel,word** etc where user can edit in same look and feel.

Comment: how can i develop a template. any idea ..pls give

Comment: Yes... You can design a HTML page with dynamic fields and same look and feel like as excel. But this not too easy and less time development. It need too much time and efforts to develop this type of app. Best idea for this is download file and then open this.